# How to Copy-Paste a table from Office apps to PyQt5 GUI?

Tags: python, pyqt5, clipboard, qtableview

I’m new in Python 3 & PyQt5 and I was faced with a problem that stunned me with its ruthlessness. I assume that my inexperience in the Python is the root cause but nevertheless…

**Task**

The task is to copy part of table from office applications (MS Office, LibreOffice) and to paste it into GUI that is implemented by PyQt5 and QTableView. I studied some simple examples on the internet, but my task is a bit more complicated. It's needed to copy some data that is surrounded by empty cells on all sides:

[image: screenshot with example]

**What has been tried**

Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V don’t work, so I tried more complicated ways listed below.

**QtWidgets.QApplication.clipboard().text()**

I started with the simplest - text content of `QtWidgets.QApplication.clipboard()` and found a complete mayhem that depends on the source of a table:

```
   MS Office Excel: '\t\t\n\t1\t2\n\t3\t4\n'
  LibreOffice Calc: '1\t2\n3\t4\n'
    MS Office Word: '\t\t\t\n\t1\t2\t\n\t3\t4\t\n\t\t\t\n'
LibreOffice Writer: '\n\n\n\n\n1\n2\n\n\n3\n4\n\n\n\n\n\n'
```

As we can see, information about empty cells is lost in many cases.

**QtWidgets.QApplication.clipboard().text("html")**

Getting the html-content of the clipboard is a solution, but in a very clumsy way. HTML-tagged text had to be carefully cleaned from any garbage tags, which MS Word produces especially much. Long, complicated, no certainty that with office upgrade I will not have to rewrite the algorithm.

**pandas.read_clipboard(header=None)**

I thought that pandas could help me, but found that output of `pandas.read_clipboard(header=None)` was close in absurdity to the `QtWidgets.QApplication.clipboard().text()` output:

```
MS Excel:
           2
0   1       
NaN NaN  NaN
    1.0  2.0
    3.0  4.0

LibreOffice Calc:
   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4

MS Word:
              3
0   1   2      
NaN NaN NaN NaN
    1.0 2.0 NaN
    3.0 4.0 NaN
    NaN NaN NaN

LibreOffice Writer:
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
```

I will be grateful if you give me a piece of advice how to solve this problem in the optimal way.

Comment: Your only hope of solving this is to examine the mime-data placed on the clipboard and hope that one of the entries preserves the relevant information in a format that can be parsed. To get a full list of the formats, do `md = QApplication.clipboard().mimeData(); for x in enumerate(md.formats()): print(x)`. For LOCalc, it creates 24 entries, but the only one that seems to preserve empty cells is `text/html`. For LOWriter, a similar html table is stored as `text/plain`. The other entires mostly hold RTF, images and LO-specific formats. So it looks like html is the best bet.

Comment: @ekhumoro, thanks a lot. But maybe then this functionality can be implemented with some module?

Comment: I don't know. I suppose you might be able to find some third-party module that can read the LO/MSO specific formats. Personally, I would just parse the html. I doubt whether the structure of the table would change very much between versions. All you need is the text content of the `td` tags.

Comment: I've already made handler that clean up html text and retains pure <td>, <tr> and <th> tags only. But for big arrays (1000 rows x 100 columns) my code operates quite much time (~20 secs). Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: Your handler must be horribly inefficient. With a dedicated parser (e.g. [lxml](https://lxml.de/)), the relevant parts can be extracted using [xpath](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath) in a fraction of a second. There's no need to "clean up" the html in any way. Just pull out the parts you need and ignore the rest.

Comment: @ekhumoro, thanks again. Dedicated parsers are quite new for me and they seem to be faster then mine. But starting test of their speed I faced with another problem, maybe you could give me advice. When I try to read clipboard with bigdata from LOCalc sometimes it seems empty:

Comment: buf = QtWidgets.QApplication.clipboard()
buf_html = buf.text('html')[0]
print('len(buf_html) = ' + str(len(buf_html)))
Outputs are:
len(buf_html) = 6665810
len(buf_html) = 0
len(buf_html) = 0
len(buf_html) = 6665810
The bigger clipboard the less chance to read it. This phenomenon occurs only on Ubuntu, not Windows

Comment: The clipboard is event-driven on X11, so try using a [single-shot timer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot) with a short delay.